# Warning failed prop type the prop 'x' is marked as required when updating mapView

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

i'm having some issues with expo/react natives mapView, the mapView is given an initial location and then i'm trying to get the users current location and update the map. 
What i currently have is:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
import {MapView, Permissions, Location} from 'expo';

export default class MapScreen extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        curLoc: { latitude: 42.229138, longitude: -122.081949 },
        curAng: 45,
        latitudeDelta: 0.922, 
        longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
    };
    this.changePosition = this.changePosition.bind(this);

}
changePosition(lat, lon){
    console.log(lat, lon)
    this.setState({curLoc: {lat, lon}});
    console.log(this.state.curLoc)
}

componentDidMount() {
    this._getLocationAsync();
}
_getLocationAsync = async () => {
    console.log("get location async hit")
    let { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.LOCATION);
    if (status !== 'granted') {
        console.log("Permission denied")



    }
    let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
    console.log(location.coords)
    tempLat = location.coords.latitude;
    temLon  = location.coords.longitude;
    console.log(this.state.curLoc)
    this.changePosition(tempLat,temLon);

}

render(){
    return(
        <MapView style={styles.fullMap}
         initialRegion={{
             latitude: this.state.curLoc.latitude,
             longitude: this.state.curLoc.longitude,
             //spread the attributes from curLoc
             latitudeDelta: this.state.latitudeDelta,
             longitudeDelta: this.state.longitudeDelta,

         }}
        />

    )
}
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
fullMap: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    height: '100%',
    width: '100%'


}
})
```

The console error i am receiving is:  Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `initialRegion.latitude` is marked as required in `MapView`, but its value is `undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in `changePosition` method while setting state using property shorthand, which sets `lat` and `lon` as state properties of `curLoc` and not updates `longitude` and `latitude` due to which `curLoc` is updated as:

```
curLoc: {lat: lat, lon: lon}
```

You can fix it by using same property name according to target property, like this:

```
changePosition(latitude, longitude){
    console.log(latitude, longitude)
    this.setState({curLoc: {latitude, longitude}});
    console.log(this.state.curLoc)
}
```

Happy Coding  [Check out](http://es6-features.org/#PropertyShorthand)

Comment: thank you! exactly what i needed and will keep it in mind for the future